# submitHandler is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, submit

my script is working but still i have this error
**submitHandler is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick**

this is the form

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="" class="form-inline pt-5 mt-5 mt-md-0">
                    <div class="group mx-auto">
                        <input name="name" id="name" class="form-input" type="text" required>
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <label class="label">Имя</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group mx-auto">
                        <input name="tel" id="tel" class="form-input" type="text" required>
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <label class="label">Телефон</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" onclick="submitHandler(myform)" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto submit">
                </form>
```

and this is my simple jquery validation script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            tel: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        submitHandler:function(form){
            form.submit();
            console.log("----------------------------------");
            console.log($('#name').val());
            console.log($('#tel').val());
            console.log("----------------------------------");
        }
    });

});
```

Help please!
i need to get rid of this error

Comment: **WHY** would you think to put an inline `onclick` handler in the submit button?  You are using jQuery, which eliminates the need for inline handlers; and the jQuery Validate automatically captures the click of the form's submit button.  See it works perfectly fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/zt86jwqo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have this error submitHandler is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

That's because you are trying to use an inline `onclick` handler to call a function that is built into the plugin and is *automatically handled by the plugin*.

You are using jQuery, which eliminates the need for any inline handlers; and the jQuery Validate plugin automatically captures the click of the form's submit button.

**REMOVE** the inline `onclick` handler, and everything will work as expected.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto submit">
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/zt86jwqo](http://jsfiddle.net/zt86jwqo)**

Answer (score -1):

You did not define a function submitHandler() which you call on input click onclick="submitHandler(myform)". E.G. you can submit your form on click like:

```
$('#myform').submit()
```

full code is:

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="" class="form-inline pt-5 mt-5 mt-md-0">
                    <div class="group mx-auto">
                        <input name="name" id="name" class="form-input" type="text" required>
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <label class="label">Имя</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group mx-auto">
                        <input name="tel" id="tel" class="form-input" type="text" required>
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <label class="label">Телефон</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" onclick="$('#myform').submit()" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto submit">
                </form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            tel: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            form.submit();
            console.log("----------------------------------");
            console.log($('#name').val());
            console.log($('#tel').val());
            console.log("----------------------------------");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: and to submit exactly at the same time

Comment: This is all wrong.  No inline event handlers are needed when using jQuery.